# How do you set the default email account in Windows

Tags: windows, email

Some applications and web pages cause a default email client, often Outlook, but sometimes Windows Mail, to open automatically to send an email.  How do you set this default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows XP:
**[How to make Outlook the default mail client](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223877)**

> 1. Start Internet Explorer.
> 2. On the **Tools** menu, click **Internet Options**.
> 3. Click the **Programs tab**.
> 4. In the **E-mail** list, click **Microsoft Office Outlook**.
> 5. Click **OK**.

Windows Vista:
[**Change the default e‑mail program**](http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-US/Help/b74eea3f-8769-428d-ab19-7a92db1637041033.mspx)

> 1. Open Default Programs by clicking the **Start** button, and then clicking **Default Programs**.
> 2. Click **Set your default programs**.
> 3. Under **Programs**, click the e‑mail program you'd like to use, and then click **Set this program as default**.
> 4. Click **OK**.

Answer (score 2):

I come upon this rather frequently — after MS Office updates Outlook Express is set as default mail client.

A regfile like this helps:

> `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`
>
> `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail]`
>
> `@="Microsoft Outlook"`